# How to find sample mean

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem, sampling

The standard deviation of the starter salary for economics students graduation is 4200.
Calculate the probability that sample mean of 40 student(x.bar) will be bigger than mean of the total population (mu)

In general I need to calculate what is P(x.bar>mu)

Aside of calculating the SED I don't know how to continue.

Comment: It is just as likely the mean of $40$ students is *above* the population mean as *below* the population mean, and hence the probability is $50\%$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It feels too simple. I was given this quation as part of my homework assiments rrgarding sampling distribution and the central limit theorem and I'm using nither of them in this question . From what i know in case that n>30 than samling distrubution can act as normal distribution and than I could have caculate the propability easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is just as likely the mean of $40$ students is *above* the population mean as *below* the population mean, and hence the probability is $50\%$.

(By the way, the title is extremely misleading, given you never have to "find sample mean.")